# Not sure if I would live that long for this Android Studio compilation time

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

[image]
Today I am having a cup of coffee and opened Android Studio, opened my project. Then saw this. It was fine yesterday. But today suddenly come across this ... I have tried to cleaned my project and rebuilt again, does not work. Please help...I am 32 now, I guess after 51 years I will be 83..not sure I will still know who I am, and only if I survive.

Comment: Isn't that saying it finished 4 minutes ago?

Comment: No. 4 means elapsed time.

Comment: If you live un Japan, 83 is near the average max life expectancy, but in the rest of the world you'll be dead at that time. So, better quit Android Developing and do another thing. Just my 2 cents on this.